# Dymamically Update jQuery in View From Controller in CodeIgniter

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

OK, so in a project I am working on I have certain tasks that can be pretty tedious, mainly making complex searches through my data and then generating a pdf with a report of the search.

The search is some complex sql and then I add data row by row to a pdf.

I would like to use jQuery progress bar or something similar to display the % of rows.

I realize that I can use jQuery .post() in my view to post to a controller and get a result to update, but this won't work for me is I want to use the progress of an executing function to update the view, not continually call a function on the controller.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Just a thought, I'll clarify later with an answer, but look into websockets, it might be useful for what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Add a line of code in the loop that is parsing your data that `echo`'s a js function to update the progress bar?

```
foreach($foo as $bar){
    //code to add line to pdf
    //code to calculate % done = $muchDone
    echo "<script>jsProgessPercent($muchDone);</script>";
}
```